# ReactJS: Modal trapped in navigation bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a **Modal** in **ReactJS** using **react-skylight**. I am trying to lunch the modal from the navigation bar but it is being trapped inside the navigation bar. I have tried setting the model to a higher `z-index` than the navigation bar.

This is how I am trying to launch the modal.

```
<li class="nav-item"><span><LoginModal /></span></li>
```

I am not sure if I have to use **react-router** and launch it as a route.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably you have an `overflow: hidden` somewhere in your navigation bar. Difficult to say without a screenshot.

Comment: @ManoloSantos geez your good! Thank you Manolo you have saved me day!.